# AAA AD creation getting failed for App Event Optimization

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-marketing-api

I'm getting the below error while creating AAA Ads for AEO (App Event Optimization) with FB Ads API.

```
{
  "code": 100,
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "message": "(#100) Invalid ad creative object story param(template_data) to create an AAA ad.",
  "fbtrace_id": "utrw...."
}
```

Also tried to provide below template data in the input but not working,

```
"object_story_spec": {
        "page_id": "4273...",
        "instagram_actor_id": "32746...",
        "template_data": {
            "multi_share_end_card": false,
            "link": "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com....."
        }
    }
```

Can anyone know what am I missing here?

Campaign/Adset configuration
AAA + US (country) + AEO + Purchase (event type) + LOWEST_COST_WITHOUT_CAP (Bid type)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and submitted a work order to the official, but the official has no feedback

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Hey I also met this problem, do you have any solution now?